# prevent jupyterlab from automatically starting new session for all open tabs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I shut down all kernels and close jupyterlab in the browser, but when I open it again it starts a session, and a kernel, for all opened notebooks

I'd followed the code and found that in [jupyterlab notebook code](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/57db70979b677b0c47cbecfbfbc3ba5b359bc0b3/notebook/static/notebook/js/notebook.js) the start session function calls (POST /api/sessions) on notebook load if there is not any running kernel for the current notebook. and the API [creates a session](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/8cd9a5f78af88c7eaf5affb73e79875200536fbd/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py#L92) and also [starts a kernel](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/8cd9a5f78af88c7eaf5affb73e79875200536fbd/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py#L111).

I can't find any config for stopping this action in jupyter configs or jupyterlab settings (settings -> advanced settings editor)

Comment: I absolutely agree that the default jupyterlab behavior of automatically starting kernels when opening a notebook is not useful. Often I open a notebook to compare the results or to look at the code. Did you consider filing an option to "not start kernel" ?

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent automatically starting kernels when you open a notebook by running Jupyterlab with the `jupyter lab --LabServerApp.notebook_starts_kernel=False` flag.

To make the configuration permanent, you can add
`c.LabServerApp.notebook_starts_kernel = False` to `$(jupyter --config-dir)/jupyter_lab_config.py`. If this file doesn't exist yet, generate it by running `jupyter lab --generate-config`.

See this issue comment for more details:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12019#issuecomment-1145841583